# Is there a room temperature ionic liquid permanganate

Tags: ionic-compounds

I need to figure out a permanganate based ionic liquid that is usable at room temperature. Unfortunately, information on which compounds could be usable and which ones aren't is scarce. That's why I'm asking it here.

Comment: Why do you want a room temperature liquid ionic  permanganate?

Comment: Do you recall that permanganate is a very strong oxidizing agent?

Comment: Permanganate tends to destroy organic cations at rt or just above. I once made that mistake with tetrabutyl permanganate.

Comment: @waylander boom?

Comment: Not enough to go boom but spontaneous combustion on drying

Answer (score 1):

You asked for assistance getting information about “permanganate based ionic liquid” that can be used at room temperatures. The following two articles(1,2) may qualify as “permanganate based ionic liquid”  Unfortunately, I do not have access to the full text of these articles so I do not know which ionic liquids are being used.  However, that fact that these are organic oxidation process suggest that the reactions might be done in a temperatures range which may of be useful to you.

Nevertheless, it looks like permanganate can be used in the presence of ionic liquid for some oxidation reactions.

1. > **Abstract**: The selective oxidation of primary and secondary benzylic
   > alcoholsnwith potassium permanganate in ionic liquids to give corresponding
   > aldehydes and ketones in 83–97% yields has been described.
   >
   > <sub>Anil Kumar, Nidhi Jain & S. M. S. Chauhan (2004) Oxidation of Benzylic Alcohols to Carbonyl Compounds with Potassium Permanganate in Ionic Liquids, Synthetic Communications, 34:15, 2835-2842, DOI: [10.1081/SCC-200026242](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1081/SCC-200026242?journalCode=lsyc20)</sub>
2. > **Abstract**: A ligand-free catalytic epoxidation system using
   > permanganate in a surfactant-like ionic liquid (IL) medium was
   > developed. The results indicate that the IL takes crucial effects in
   > the epoxide selectivity. The loading of permanganate is also found
   > critical in preventing over-oxidation of epoxides. The system with 0.3
   > mol% permanganate and 3.5-equivalent CH3CO3H is able to achieve
   > excellent yields and selectivity of epoxides. The study of epoxidation
   > with KMnO4 in IL medium reveals an unusual oxidation behavior of
   > permanganate not found in traditional solvents
   >
   > <sub>Lu, Yu-Jing & Wong, Wing-Leung & Chow, Cheuk-Fai. (2015). A surfactant-like ionic liquid with permanganate dissolved as a highly selective epoxidation system. Catalysis Communications. 69. 25-28. [10.1016/j.catcom.2015.05.020](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277652749_A_surfactant-like_ionic_liquid_with_permanganate_dissolved_as_a_highly_selective_epoxidation_system).</sub>

Comment: No, I am afraid this is not correct. Here the ionic liquid is being used as solvent and potassium permanganate as a reagent.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thank you for point out the reagent nature of the permanganate in the examples I provided.  Does this suggest there is an a priori reason that KMnO4 can not be an ionic liquid constituent?  Is permanganate simply too oxidative to allow the existence of the other component of an ionic liquid?

Comment: Usually the required anion is incorporated in ILs by ion-exchange resins. I think KMnO4 will easily oxidize these resins too. The anion is incompatible with most organic substances.